# Disable "try it out" button in springfox 2.9 based on roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger-ui

Currently I am disabling swagger ui try-it-out button using following code

```
@Bean
public UiConfiguration tryItOutConfig() {
        final String[] methodsWithTryItOutButton = { "" };
        return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder().supportedSubmitMethods(methodsWithTryItOutButton).build();
    }
```

But the problem is, it will disable it for everyone. I want to enable buttons for user with some role. Is it possible to do it.